# How Did The Coronavirus Market Crash Cause Excessive Price Rises Of Luxury Goods?

Tags: macroeconomics, stock-market, covid-19-crisis

The COVID-19 pandemic had caused the unemployment rate to rise quite significantly in many countries. Furthering this, most countries are facing economic crises, most notably, the United States with rising inflation.

Yet still, with people facing reduced salaries and in turn, reduced savings, how is it possible that the price of luxury goods such as that of cars, watches and sneakers have risen by more than 150% ?

Comment: Savings increased significantly during the [pandemic]([https://www.kansascityfed.org/ten/2021-spring-ten-magazine/study-shows-surge-in-savings-during-the-pandemic/). Card face significant supply chain disruptions (microchips etc). I am not sure a sneaker is a luxury good? Neither are watches, unless it's collectibles / expensive watches.

Comment: @Jamoe Can you please edit your question so that it contains a link to statistics backing up your claim "*the price of luxury goods [...] have risen by more than 150%*"? This way we can see how exactly you define luxury goods.

Comment: There is a distinction between what happened during Covid and lockdown, and what happened afterwards.  In some cases such as cars, production capacity was reduced either for the finished product or for some components, and when demand recovered supply was slow to respond, leading to price rises

Comment: You sort of answered your own question, partially. You stated that there is rising inflation, so of course, this also affects luxury products. Another reason is that the reduced incomes did not affect all people equally and the richer people, who are likelier to demand luxury goods, most likely lost a smaller share of f their income on average.